# How can I limit CiviDiscount codes to be used for a maximum number of participants rather than amount of times?

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

For some of the events we host we want to give our sponsors a certain number of free/discounted tickets. We allow them to purchase tickets for multiple participants at the same time.

We have set up discount codes for each of the sponsors that can be used a limited number of times. but this doesn't prevent them signing up 10 people at one time and therefore purchasing 10 tickets but only using up one discount code.

Is there a way to limit the number of participants a discount code can be used for rather than limiting by the number of times it is used? or is there another way we could achieve this?

Ideally if the sponsor wanted to purchase 10 tickets all at the same time but only get 5 discounted tickets they would get the first 5 for the discounted price and the next 5 they would need to pay full price for.

Comment: I'd like to know this too. 
I have a similar issue - to offer a £30- discount on whatever is bought (the £30- is a constant, no matter how many tickets / memberships).

If anyone has a solution it's be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might try installing the Redeem By Participant extension, which changes CiviDiscount's default behavior of only incrementing the use count by 1 no matter how many registrations are included in a single transaction. With this extension, if a sponsor purchases 10 tickets at the same time, the use count of the discount code would be incremented by 10 (rather than by 1), which may help your use case.

https://github.com/ginkgostreet/com.ginkgostreet.cividiscount.rbp

(I realize this is a very old question, and you may have solved this already, but this is an option that might help someone else.)